# MongoDB database administration GUI

Tags: windows, database, mongodb

Please suggest a good GUI-based tool for [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) database administration.

Requirements:

- Connect to DB on local or network server.
- Data view and editing features.
- Free or Open Source
- Support Indexing Related Features

Optional Requirements:

- Query builder

I am using Windows 8.

Comment: See also: [This closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310242/do-any-visual-tools-exist-for-mongodb-for-windows/6691013#6691013) on Stack Overflow, it would be nice if these posts could be combined somehow. The SO post seems to be more up to date.

Answer (score 9):

I used [Mongovue](http://blog.mongovue.com/) once, I might be a good fit for your needs.

It is what you except it to be from a DB management UI:
[image]

Here's the feature list:

- Open multiple connections to different MongoDB servers
- View your MongoDB database as a hierarchical tree consisting of databases, collections, indexes and users
- Peek at db and collection stats at the click of your mouse
- Add new databases and collections easily through the GUI
- Easily build indexes – either specify Json or use the point and click (visual) interface
- Run Map-Reduce operations easily. Get syntax highlighting for your Javascript functions while typing
- Import relational data from MySQL, SQLServer or PostgreSQL into MongoDB automatically and start building your applications right away
- User Manager – add / edit / change password
- Export your data (documents) to CSV, MS Excel or Json formats
- Get a quick overview of your database
- Use a highly customized and specifically designed interface for GridFS
- Monitor the performance of your production servers under “Server Monitoring” view
- Learn MongoDB shell commands as you use different views in MongoVUE
- Copy collections from a database to another database (on a different or same server)
- Duplicate or create copies of collections

It has [multiple editions](http://www.mongovue.com/purchase/), ranges from free to $2.5K, but it your requirements are well covered in the free edition IMHO.

Comment: Seems like Mongovue may have gone dormant in the time since this answer was written.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/):

- free and open source
- Windows/Linux/Mac

The main difference with Mongovue is that it is shell-centric (while Mongovue is really GUI). So in some sense it is half a GUI, half a CLI, with all the pros and cons CLI and GUI have.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com/). It's basically the equivalent of PHPMyAdmin for MongoDB (i.e. web-based, and you need a PHP server). It does all you asked for, and has a few more features:

- Open source under New BSD License
- Runs fast, and easy to install
- I18N (English, Chinese, French, Japanese, British, Spanish, German, Italian, Russian)
- Plug-ins: everyone can develop his own plug-in
- Themes: you can custom themes easily for your users or company

System:

- Multiple hosts, and one host can has multiple administrators
- Switch among hosts freely
- Password protection
- Server
- Server info (web server, PHP, directives in PHP.ini ...)
- Status
- Databases
- Replication status

Database:

- Query, create, drop, repair
- Execute commands and javascript codes
- Statistics
- Profiling
- Users management
- Data transfer(clone)
- Export/import

Collection:

- Advanced query and explain tool
- Read, insert, update, duplicate and remove single row
- Query, create and drop indexes
- Validate collection
- Clear all records in collection
- Remove and change a batch of criteria matched rows
- Statistics
- Rename
- Modify properties (capped, size, max ...)
- Data transfer(clone)
- Export/import
- GridFS
- View chunks
- Download file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef):

- Windows, Mac, and Linux
- Free for non-commercial use
- I find the interface much more responsive than MongoVUE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recently I discovered a tool simply called DbSchema ( http://www.dbschema.com ). First of all I was impressed because they do diagrams for MongoDB.
Second I found great an data explorer from them, where you can explore data from each collection and sub-documents in a separate window.

Now I am dealing with virtual foreign key from them, to explore data from two collections bind referencing one the other via ObjectId's.Look for DbSchema tool, is great for the diagrams they do for MongoDB, query builder and data explorer.Some features you may discover inside like virtual foreign keys makes the interaction really similar with relational databases, where you can place data in multiple collections and join it with ObjectId's.I was surprised to see is possible to have diagrams for MongoDB as well, as for any relational database.

Go for the tool DbSchema. Have a look on relational data browse and the virtual foreign keys there, 
they are a step forward in designing a database with data over multiple collections and references between them via ObjectId's.

[image]

Comment: Please revise the text of your post as it is kind of hard to read and understand what DbSchema is actually capable of. Remove duplicate sentences (and add spaces in between sentences).